# How to insert code dynamicly into head within a Next.js application?

Tags: next.js

I want to show to Google the relationship between pages with my pagination implementation.Therefor I want to add for example this code block in `head`:

```
<link rel="prev" href="https://www.example.com/article?story=abc&page=1" />
<link rel="next" href="https://www.example.com/article?story=abc&page=3" />
```

When I add this to a variable or make it dynamical with a function it isn't shown in `head` in my `Next.js` application.

For example:

```
const pageRelationships = `<link rel="prev" href="https://www.example.com/article?story=abc&page=1" /><link rel="next" href="https://www.example.com/article?story=abc&page=3" />`
```

Implementing it in `head`:

```
<Head>
{pageRelationships}
</Head>
```

Do you have suggestions how to insert the code block in `head`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can use this code:

```js
// Make sure that we are on the client side
if(typeof document !== 'undefined') {
  const firstLinkElement = docment.createElement("link");
  firstLinkElement.rel = "prev";
  firstLinkElement.href = "https://www.example.com/article?story=abc&page=1";
  document.head.appendChild(firstLinkElement);
  const secondLinkElement = docment.createElement("link");
  secondLinkElement.rel = "next";
  secondLinkElement.href = "https://www.example.com/article?story=abc&page=3";
  document.head.appendChild(secondLinkElement);
}
```

Or this one:

```js
// Make sure that we are on the client side
if(typeof document !== 'undefined') {
  const pageRelationships = `<link rel="prev" href="https://www.example.com/article?story=abc&page=1" /><link rel="next" href="https://www.example.com/article?story=abc&page=3" />`;
  document.head.innerHTML = document.head.innerHTML + pageRelationships;
}
```